# In IE8 -ms-filter background disappears when height is higher than window. (when scrollbar appears)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, background, gradient

In IE8, when div is higher than window, -ms-filter background disappears. In IE7 and below works fine. (I could use 1px transparent image, but what if I would need to use transparent color plus background image)

Sample code and fiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sk">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html,body{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
        #one{
            float:left;
            height:100%;
            width:50%;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CC917C6F,endColorstr=#CC917C6F)";
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CC917C6F,endColorstr=#CC917C6F);
        }
        #two{
            float:right;
            height:101%;
            width:50%;
            background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CCAAAA6F,endColorstr=#CCAAAA6F)";
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CCAAAA6F,endColorstr=#CCAAAA6F);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9dmqg/4/
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the fixed height for p tag. make that fixed height as `min-height` and add `height:auto`

```
#one p {
     height:auto; min-height:800px;
}
#two p {
    height:auto; min-height:800px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9dmqg/3/)**

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. (IE8) 
I am not looking for some kind of clearfix.
I updated question, found, that problem is not from p, but directly from div.